# What is the definition of the term "Dente" in financial terms?

Tags: definição

I was working on a huge project and came across this term in an invoice.

Here is a portion of it. You can barely read it, but I circled it in red. I need this term in English.

[image: See circled word in red.]

[image: Another example.]

Comment: @Hugo não tens mais informação que possas passar? Não será um erro ortográfico. "Doente" talvez?!

Comment: As a Software Developer that image seems to me like a generic invoice report that is used for all kinds of surgeries and there is a bug showing a field ("dente") which should not be seen in a hernia surgery invoice. The fact that the invoice shows "data-ini" instead of "Data de Início" makes me think this invoice has not been thoroughly tested.

Comment: Did you find any examples where the "Dente" column wasn't blank?

Comment: As a translator, this kind of anomaly is generally handled like this: **tooth [sic]**. That way the pressure is off you. I doubt it means doente, in the middle of the column like that.

Comment: Provavelmente é uma abreviação, podendo ser uma palavra encurtada, ou uma abreviação de 4 palavras, então provavelmente se isto, só o desenvolvedor do software vai poder lhe confirmar.

Comment: Qual a necessidade de fazer a pergunta em ingles?

Comment: @EnnioSousa buy a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Em faturamento de procedimentos odontológicos é comum a obrigatoriedade de indicação dos dentes a intervir.

Considerando que a planilha se trata de faturamento na área de saúde, os procedimentos odontológicos normalmente levam a indicação do número do dente de 1 a 32 conforme o odontograma.

[image]